# How do you make a three two-input and gates function as four-input and gate

Tags: transistors, digital-logic, integrated-circuit, logic-gates, boolean-algebra

I'm having a hard time trying to recreate this logic. I used the output of my two and gates connected to another AND gate will that work? or is there any better solution to this problem?

[image: my first attempt on creating a three input and gate function as a four input and gate]

Comment: It's a perfectly good 4-input AND gate equivalent for me

Comment: Yes, that will work. If there is any better (cheaper) solution, depends on the real application and what you have available. But if you have three unused AND-gates, there is probably no better solution than this.

Comment: @Klas-Kenny how about this https://imgur.com/a/F481nd8

Comment: `how about this` ... maybe ... investigate `open collector output` and `wired OR`

Comment: @JohnNazarene IF the gates has open collector outputs and you add an pull-up resistor, that would work. But connecting standard push/pull outputs together like that does not work well.

Comment: @jsotola thanks for the info I really need to know much of that

Comment: Of course there are better solution, like a real quad input AND:D and the wired and is really only good at very low frequencies. But from a logic synthesis perspective AFAIK there isn't a better solutio

Comment: @John Nazarene Yep, you answered your own question ...

Answer (score 0):

What you have done in your circuit is using the associative property of a the AND operation:

$$A\cdot B\cdot C = (A\cdot B)\cdot C = A\cdot (B\cdot C)$$

So

$$A\cdot B\cdot C\cdot D = (A\cdot B)\cdot (C\cdot D)$$

This right-hand side is the schematic that you have shown.

Alternatively, you can also use De Morgan's law. For boolean operations, this translates to the following equivalents:

$$A\cdot B = \overline{\overline{A} + \overline{B}}$$
$$A + B = \overline{\overline{A} \cdot \overline{B}}$$

This allows you to make many equivalent circuits. For example:

$$A\cdot B\cdot C\cdot D = \overline{\overline{A\cdot B} + \overline{C\cdot B}}$$[image: Example of De Morgan]

When wiring up boolean logic, never short two or more logic gate outputs together (at least not conceptually). This can cause two logic gates to apply conflicting values to a node (i.e. both a '0' and a '1' simultaneously), which is conceptually and in theory an impossibility.

Answer (score 0):

Define "better".

If you need faster propagation from one input signal but the others are less critical, then this gives one gate delay to input D, 2 to input C, and 3 to A and B - instead of a uniform 2 gate delay. There are *rare* circumstances were this can improve the speed of the overall circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fO5TSS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

But usually, what you have is optimal.